# Double to Binary

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста методы для перевода чисел в двоичный вид.
Для чисел типа `Integer` есть статический метод `toBinaryString(int I)`.
А теперь очень нужен метод для перевода чисел типа `Double`, однако похожего метода в `Double` я не нашел.

Comment: `Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(ЧИСЛО))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ссылаясь на ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359918/6104996):

`Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))` должно прекрасно работать.

```
System.out.println("0:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0D)));
System.out.println("1:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(1D)));
System.out.println("2:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(2D)));
System.out.println("2^900:            0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Math.pow(2, 900))));
System.out.println("Double.MAX_VALUE: 0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.MAX_VALUE)));

/*
    выведет:
    0:                0b0
    1:                0b11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    2:                0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    2^900:            0b111100000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    Double.MAX_VALUE: 0b111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
*/
```